# Request must have at least one newMediaItem - Google Photos API

Tags: google-photos-api

I'm trying to create media item using Google Photos API. Endpoint is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/batchCreate). If I copy and paste my payload to an API explorer which can be found in documentation, I get success:
[Request inputed to an API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH3ik.png) and [Successful  response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM36l.png).

If I do the same in my node js program, I'm getting an error.

This is what I do:

```
const accessToken = "MyAccessToken";
payload = {
    "newMediaItems": [
        {
            "description": "picture",
            "simpleMediaItem": {
                "uploadToken": "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"
            }
        }
    ]
};
   const response = await fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
```

And getting this response:

```
{ error:
   { code: 400,
     message: 'Request must have at least one newMediaItem.',
     status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' } }
```

What could go wrong here?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the JSON payload in the wrong parameter in your call to `fetch`. It should be set in the parameter `body` (and not in `payload`). The JSON itself looks okay.

This snippet should work:

```
const response = await fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
});
```

Source: [node-fetch 'Post with JSON' example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-json)